# the main usage of the "to" as a prepositional condition

Tags: grammar, word-usage

when I was young I wasn't from the English area but I am used to learning English grammar already. 
Well , I am still thinking about one thing maybe because I had not even got to learn this grammar until I have realized that is such use in English . Nobody has even said to me that an -ing form can be added after the "to" in actually . What I used to learn was all about the infinitives (base verbs) only . 
I have seen and gone through the post in this webpage but I still cannot understand about it. So what can I actually do so that I can always be able to identify the differences about those situations hence I must able to make it clear about whether to put a gerund or a base verb after that particular "to" ? =(

Comment: You might get more help at [our sister site](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

Only if you can put [*to* + noun] after a certain verb would you usually use [*to* + verb-*ing*] when using a gerund. The reason is that a gerund functions like a noun, so it can regularly be replaced with a noun. An asterisk indicates a sentence that is not grammatical.

> *She likes to eggs.
> *She likes to eating.
>
> She consented to an evacuation.
> She consented to evacuating the area.

Note that the first group of verbs is far more common than the last, so [*to* + verb-*ing*] is uncommon.

Comment: Nice concise answer.

Comment: Mismatcher brain in overdrive. She applied to the board =/=> she applied to boarding. I'd better post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Cerberus's answer (and ignoring travel verbs such as go / walk / drive / travel):

These verbs are commonly followed by the preposition ‘to’:

```
       answer to (someone) 
       appeal to (someone or someone's affections)
       apply to (something)              
       react to (something)
```

but don't commonly accept a [doing something] object (?) for the preposition.

These verbs do:

```
       apply oneself to [doing] something     
       aspire to [doing] something 
       attend to [doing] something 
       be resigned to [doing] something
       commit oneself to [doing] something 
       confess to [doing] something
       devote oneself to [doing] something 
       react to [doing] (something)
       refer to [doing] (something)
       resort to [doing] something
       see to [doing] something
       subject someone to [doing] something 
       turn to [doing] something)
```

Comment: If you demand that a verb be used that requires a "to someone", then by definition no gerund is possible, because gerunds, unlike corporations, are not people. But this is a semantic problem rather than a syntactic one. Unlike *answer to* and *appeal to*, however, I don't see a problem with *apply* and *react*: *this law does not apply to killing a murderer; she reacted badly to losing her brother*.

Comment: Oh, I see I forgot to +1 you. Good examples.

Comment: Yes, I was so busy trying to straighten out the formatting I lost track of the actual content. I've got _react to_ in both classes, though I missed the apply to [doing] something, with that sense for 'apply'.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even realise you had *react* in both classes!